# Detect Google drive file coming from Trash

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, google-drive-api

I am using the following code to fetch all the files present in my Google cloud.

```
_driveService.Files.List().Fetch();
```

But it fetches even files that are moved to trash. How to know if the file is from trash or from normal folder? I cant see any attribute to the file which specifies that it is from Trash. Can some one help me to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When retrieving files with the Drive API, you can check the `labels` collection to see if it contains the `trashed` field:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#labels.trashed

Answer (score 1):

You use the Child API to get a list of the files in trash and exclude them from the transfer see link:
[Child List](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list).

Comment: I meant the same when I said above answer. Answer above your answer :)